# Generate HTML in ERB Template View

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, generate

I need to add options to a HTML-selector combobox inside an ERB template. First I create an array named `var_arr` with `<option value="foo">Foo</option>`-items out of an array with items/values like `foo` and then I try to write it between the `<select></select>`-tags with `each`

```
<% var_arr.each do |option| %>
  <%= option %> 
<% end %>
```

What it generates is

```
<option value="article">Article</option> <option value="link">Link</option> <option value="photo">Photo</option> <option value="treenode">TreeNode</option>
```

But it's not treated as HTML. The options aren't displayed as options in the dropdown menu.

Where's the hidden caveat here?

Yours

von Spotz

Comment: <% var_arr.each do |option| %>
  <%= option.html_safe %> 
<% end %>

Try this.

Comment: Would like to have this be the accepted answer! Thank you !

Comment: Welcome, and I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ERB treats the text from variables as text and not as html you need to mark the options as html_safe to treat it as html like this.

```
<% var_arr.each do |option| %>
  <%= option.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```